# Numpy performance gap between len(arr) and arr.shape[0]

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, micro-optimization

I've found that `len(arr)` is almost twice as fast as `arr.shape[0]` and am wondering why.

I am using Python 3.5.2, Numpy 1.14.2, IPython 6.3.1

The below code demonstrates this:

```
arr = np.random.randint(1, 11, size=(3, 4, 5))

%timeit len(arr)
# 62.6 ns ± 0.239 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit arr.shape[0]
# 102 ns ± 0.163 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

I've also done some more tests for comparison:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.shape = (3, 4, 5)        

foo = Foo()

%timeit arr.shape
# 75.6 ns ± 0.107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit foo.shape
# 61.2 ns ± 0.281 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit foo.shape[0]
# 78.6 ns ± 1.03 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

So I have two questions:

1) Why does `len(arr)` works faster than `arr.shape[0]`? (I would have thought `len` would be slower because of the function call)

2) Why does `foo.shape[0]` work faster than `arr.shape[0]`? (In other words, what overhead does do numpy arrays incur in this case?)

Comment: @user3483203, are you sure? Just I don't see any `()` it means that code should only get a field, I mean no calls, isn't it?

Comment: The time complexity of `len` is O(1) in CPython I believe.

Comment: Times are `ns`, and depend on the calling details, not on the size of the array.  Why should it matter?  I rarely use `len(arr)`, since `shape[0]` is much more explicit (to human eyes).  We'd have to dig into the `ndarray` code to see the calling sequence `len => .__len__ =>?`, `shape` must be coded as a property, not a pure attribute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The numpy array data structure is implemented in C.  The dimensions of the array are stored in a C structure.  They are not stored in a Python tuple.  So each time you read the `shape` attribute, a new Python tuple of new Python integer objects is created.  When you use `arr.shape[0]`, that tuple is then indexed to pull out the first element, which adds a little more overhead. `len(arr)` only has to create a Python integer.

You can easily verify that `arr.shape` creates a new tuple each time it is read:

```
In [126]: arr = np.random.randint(1, 11, size=(3, 4, 5))

In [127]: s1 = arr.shape

In [128]: id(s1)
Out[128]: 4916019848

In [129]: s2 = arr.shape

In [130]: id(s2)
Out[130]: 4909905024
```

`s1` and `s2` have different `id`s; they are different tuple objects.